# Relative Date Formatting, output for past dates?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

I am looking at using `-[NSDateFormatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:]` to present dates as "Today" or "Yesterday". I am only looking at dates in the past but am curious what options I would see localised for the UK.

Just

- "Today"
- "Yesterday"

or anything more convoluted like

- "The day before yesterday"

Are the possible outputs listed anywhere so I can get an idea of the screen space needed to correctly display them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. They are listed in your console window when you run the following program:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter  alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
        [formatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];

        NSCalendar * cal = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCalendar];
        NSDateComponents * minusOneDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [minusOneDay setDay:-1];
        NSDate * today = [NSDate date];
        NSDate * date = [NSDate date];

        while( 1 > [[cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date toDate:today options:0] year] ){

            NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
            date = [cal dateByAddingComponents:minusOneDay
                                        toDate:date
                                       options:0];
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

In my locale, the list seems to just be "Tomorrow", "Today", and "Yesterday".

Comment: It's different for other languages. In French, for one, there is a "day after tomorrow" case.

Comment: @KevinConner: Date formatters are aware of the current locale, so this is accounted for.